# Regex Match Null Cells

Tags: c#, excel, interop

i tried using a regex in my functon. It allows to find the cell which has the specified string in the regex(ignoring the case).

**The problem is**, if I have empty boxes just before the cell, I have an exception.
I don't understand why NULL cells are a problem.

My function :

```
public int FindSearchableCol()
{
    var j = 1;
    var x = FindMainInfoStartRow();
    var i = x;
    string test = ws.Cells[i, j].Value2;
    Regex searchable = new Regex(@"(?<=\*)(searchable)(?=\*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = searchable.Matches(ws.Cells[i, j].Value2);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                return j;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
                if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 == "*MAIN INFO END*")
                {
                    i = x;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get, and on what line?

Comment: i got 'System.ArgumentNullException'  at the line 'MatchCollection matches = searchable.Matches(ws.Cells[i, j].Value2);'

Comment: VS told me the value cannot be null

Comment: You are reading an excel worksheet (I can tell from Value2). A worksheet has a used range that starts at a default size and grows as you add data.  It looks like your variable j may be outside the range (also i).  Suppose the Used Range was 10 rows x 10 columns (A1:J10).  So if you find an item in cell J5.  You code then increments J by 1 and you are now is column K which is outside the used range.

Comment: @jdweng the code is working without null value (with white space), the problem is only the null value.

Comment: The problem is ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 is null.  So check if ws.Cells[i, j] == null

Comment: the value is null the error provide from the treatment ok the null value  with Regex.Match how can i pass the null value ?

Comment: _" how can i pass the null value ?"_ As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) say, Matches throws an ArgumentNullException if the input is null. So you can use `searchable.Matches(ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 ?? string.Empty)`

Comment: @stuartd Tkanks ! that's it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use :

`MatchCollection matches = searchable.Matches(ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 ?? string.Empty)`

instead :

`MatchCollection matches = searchable.Matches(ws.Cells[i, j].Value2)`